# Stop Cycle feature panorama windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cycle, panorama-control

Is there a way or a workaround to disable the cycle-feature of panorama control in windows phone 7?

Im asking this because I got several scrollviewers together and the best way I found was using the panorama control.

Comment: I can't get the point why you would like to disable the cycle-feature.